# Пройтись по двум контейнерам с помощью STL - алгоритма

Tags: c++, stl

Есть задача: сложить произведение элементов двух контейнеров.

```
//объявление v1, v2, res, проверка на равенство размеров...
for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    res += v1[i] * v2[i];
```

Вроде норм, но захотелось здесь использовать stl-алгоритм, чтобы перемещаться с помощью итераторов (лучше если используем std::list). Не нашел ничего адекватного. Может кто знает, как решить задачу с помощью stl?

Пока формулировал - пришла идея сделать вот так:

```
std::vector<int> temp(v1);
std::transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), v2.begin(), temp.begin(), [](int l, int r)
{
    return l * r;
});

auto res = std::accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0);
```

Тоже выглядит не очень - появляется переменная temp, которую нужно проинициализировать + два раза обойти. Хочется уметь 
 просто способ для действий над элементами контейнеров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь алгоритмом [`inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product).

```
//объявление v1, v2, res, проверка на равенство размеров...
auto res = std::inner_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо!) Решить задачу получилось вот так:
`int res = std::inner_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 0, std::plus<int>(), std::multiplies<int>());`

Comment: Можно было не писать plus и multiplies - у данного алгоритма это параметры по умолчанию..